# How to perform read operations from primary only

Tags: java, mongodb, jakarta-ee

We are using Mongo DB for our Java Java EE based application.
We are using one primary and two secondary as part of cluster of Mongo DB 
The Mongo DB is continuously read / Updated / Write as part of our architecture.

Due to this we are getting Dirty Reads ( zero values ) When we do  a fetch operation from Mongo DB.

TO solve this, I am trying to configure it in such a way that the read operation always fetches from primary itself and writes / updates can go to primary / secondary.

Please let me know if this is possible (always read from primary and use any thing primary/secondary for write/update)

And will it have any negative impact with such a design?

Comment: "Any negative impact" - obviously, your primary node is the bottleneck now, as it has to handle both reads and writes. If network is saturated, or you fire an expensive update (that blocks readers), then you're in trouble.

Comment: Also, you can only write to primary. You can't write to secondary.

Comment: Thank you , that makes sense , i will rule out such a attempt .

Comment: Any idea how Dirty Reads can be avoided ??

Comment: i think `Dirty Reads` means the program got uncommitted data, before other ones commit their write. but in your case, looks like you wanna got the data written by others ASAP. if i got your meaning, maybe you could move the ASAP part of your data to some super-cow-powered big memory and fast disk host, one node, no secondary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to mongoDB uses staged writing in inserts, you can have lag in write operations even in a single node. 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-journal

Use write concern to avoid problems (with dirty data): http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html

You can read more about write operations:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations/

Which states that using writes without error check is not recommended for production.

Answer (score 1):

To exclude slave reads you have to set a corresponding [ReadPreference](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/ReadPreference.html). See documentation on [Mongo](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/Mongo.html) connection class.

Something like this:

```
 mongo.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.primary());
```

The documentation says, however, that by default all reads should already go to primary:

> By default, all read and write operations will be made on the primary, but it's possible to read from secondaries by changing the read preference:

Are you sure you didn't turn slave reads on in the app?

Comment: Thanks , but if i do so , as you said there will be negative impact know ?? as the master gets bottle necked ??

Comment: @PreethiJain: that's the price. You want to scale reads - add slaves. You want to scale writes - add shards.

Comment: Ya i am sure we didn't turn slave reads on the app. Thanks for the response .