# MongoDB : How to find if slaveOk=true is set or not

Tags: mongodb

We are using  Mongo DB in our Application .
We have one primary and one secondary for this purpose .

How can i make sure that my Application is reading data from Primary Or Secondary ??

My question is how can i know  if slaveOk=true is set or not ??

Thanks in advance .

**Edited Part**

Not sure of the Driver what i am uisng 
I am connecting Mongo DB through Java as shown

```
ServerAddress addr = new ServerAddress(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
servAddrList.add(addr);
}
MongoOptions options = new MongoOptions();
options.autoConnectRetry = true;
options.connectionsPerHost = Config.intParam(
"mongo.connectionsPerHost", 1200);      
mongo = new Mongo("10.11.13.111", 27017);
```

And i am using mongo 2.4.jar

Please let m know how can i find what driver i am using ??

Comment: Which driver are you using?

Comment: Please see the edited part.

Comment: You are directly connecting to the host using only 1 host address and haven't specified slaveok, therefore your data is coming from the ip that you connect.

Comment: btw, one primary and one secondary replica is not good. more overhead cost for transfering data from primary to secondary, and either of them is down, the replica is down, less stable than one server. add another server, both a secondary or a arbiter count.

Comment: I added mongo.slaveOk() and gave it a slave IP , its throwing an exception , Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException: not talking to master and retries used up

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for in my opinion is readPreference : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/replication/#replica-set-read-preference

In the api (http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.10.1/com/mongodb/ReadPreference.html) documentation there is an isSlaveOk() method : http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.10.1/com/mongodb/ReadPreference.html#isSlaveOk()

See this question: [How to perform read operations from primary only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575948/how-to-perform-read-operations-from-primary-only/14577035#14577035)

There is the answer for setting read preference

```
mongo.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.primary());
```

and your answer is to get read preference:

```
mongo.getReadPreference().isSlaveOk();
```

Unfortunately these features do not exist in versions after 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

looks like earlier java driver just have `mongo.slaveOk()` method, call it and it is slaveOk. no way to examine.

Comment: suggest you using newer java driver, like 2.10 or so. less bug, more feature.